# Remote debugging, debug html button click

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I am trying to work through a rather large application but am having troubles debugging a button click.  It's a java EE application and there are some html files that we create a template with, then write it to the browser via PrintWriter.

I'm new to remote debugging and I am able to have the debugger pick up the tomcat server I am running the application from.  The app is a two-window type application, where the 2nd window has a submit button.  I am having a heck of a time getting the debugger to pick up on that second button click, and since there are no click events, since it's an HTML document, how would i pick up this button click in the debugger?